# Is it possible to clone a ValueType?

Tags: c#, reflection, clr, value-type

Is it possible to clone an object, when it's known to be a boxed ValueType, without writing type specific clone code?

Some code for reference

```
List<ValueType> values = new List<ValueType> {3, DateTime.Now, 23.4M};
DuplicateLastItem(values);
```

The partical issue I have is with a value stack based virtual instruction machine. (And Im too lazy to write typeof(int) typeof(DateTime)....)

**update** I think I confused myself (and a few other people). The working solution I have is;

```
List<ValueType> values = new List<ValueType> { 3, DateTime.Now, 23.4M }; 

// Clone
values.Add(values[values.Count() - 1]);

// Overwrite original
values[2] = 'p';

foreach (ValueType val in values)
   Console.WriteLine(val.ToString());
```

Comment: Jon Jon Jon, come out wherever you are..

Comment: Eventually, you will have to type the "type of the variable" if you were to unbox it. Could you give an example of what are you trying to achieve? The "dynamic" keyword in c# 4 might be of help here.

Comment: what does DuplicateLastItem do?

Comment: @shahkalpesh DuplicateLastItem duplicates the last item, this is where the "clone" magic goes.

Comment: values.Add(values[values.Count]? or values.Add(values[values.Count -1]?

Comment: @shahkalpesh that would make a copy of the reference, Ian wants to clone the object instance.

Comment: @Yannick: If I understand it correctly, value types are copied by value and the reference is not copied. i.e if you change the value of the last element (after the above code), it won't affect the previous element.

Comment: @Ian: What do you expect in the "values", after DuplicateItem is called? Do you want it behave such that any change in the last element, should result in change to "new" last element (i.e. the one after the call to DuplicateValues)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know, if I have totally misunderstood the question.
Are you trying to do this?

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<ValueType> values = new List<ValueType> {3, DateTime.Now, 23.4M};
    DuplicateLastItem(values);

    Console.WriteLine(values[2]);
    Console.WriteLine(values[3]);
    values[3] = 20;
    Console.WriteLine(values[2]);
    Console.WriteLine(values[3]);
}

static void DuplicateLastItem(List<ValueType> values2)
{
    values2.Add(values2[values2.Count - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a hack using `Convert.ChangeType`:

```
object x = 1;
var type = x.GetType();
var clone = Convert.ChangeType(x, type);

// Make sure it works
Assert.AreNotSame(x, clone);
```

The result is copy of the value boxed in new object.

Comment: Im not sure about the guts of the CLR but the solution I have works. As you've said in the comments to another answer, you've probably caught the CLR doing something "clever"

Comment: This seems like the right approach in the only situation I can see where the question makes sense: one has a reference to a heap object whose type known to be a struct but is otherwise unknown, and one wishes to make a memberwise clone of it.  Still seems like an odd question, since one can't really do much with a heap object without knowing its type unless it implements an interface, and if one is going to define a struct to implement an interface one may as well include a proper clone function in that interface.

Answer (score 5):

Every assignment of a valuetype is by definition a clone.

Edit:

When boxing a valuetype a copy of your valuetype will be contained in an instance of a ReferenceType.

Depending of the Cloning method, I don't foresee any differences.

Comment: This is about boxed values no?

Comment: "Every assignment of a valuetype is by definition a clone."

Wrong. Assignment does not "clone" a value type. You get a reference to the same value.

Comment: Jorge, this is the fundamental difference between ValueTypes and ReferenceTypes. `int i = 1; int a = i;` <- a will be a clone of i

Comment: Boxed values are not stored in instances of Object, they have their own corresponding reference types. The type of Object is not the same as the type of Int32.

Comment: Brian, you're absolutely right. I was oversimplifying, but the bottomline is the same.

Comment: I mean value types have special semmantics so that x = x + 1 results in a new value, and x holds a reference to that value. That's immutability, internally the CLR doesn't create a new item on the stack each time you just make an assignment.

Comment: Yannick I susppect (and I'm just guessing) indeed i and a internally refer to the same object, if you "try" to modify i you just end up pointing to a new value type so that a still points to the old one... that would avoid a lot of wasted space in the stack

Comment: Jorge, I see what you mean, sounds plausible.

Comment: Jorge: One thing to keep in mind though is scope. Depending on the scope of the 'copied' valuetype, it might be impossible to refer to the same value on the stack.

Comment: If `U` inherits from `T`,  `List<U>.Enumerator` may be boxed as an `IEnumerator<T>`.  Further, copying or unboxing a `List<U>.Enumerator` to another value of that type will take a snapshot of its state.  Given a reference to an `IEnumerator<T>` which one knows to be a `List<U>.Enumerator` for some unknown type `U`, is there any nice way to clone its state?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need cloning code anyway? Value types *should* usually be immutable anyway and this isn’t changed by boxing. Therefore, a well-designed value type has no requirement for cloning.

Comment: Exactly. Its important to phrase the question & a code example with what is expected always helps.

Comment: Suppose one has an `IEnumerator<T>` which one knows is a `List<U>.Enumerator` for some unknown type `U` that derives from `T`.  If one knew `U`, casting to `List<U>.Enumerator` would take a snapshot of its state, but doing that would require knowing type `U`.

Comment: @supercat Uhm, I think you accidentally commented on the wrong post. At least I don’t see the connection.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The type `List<T>.Enumerator` is a widely used self-mutating structure type which is frequently boxed.  For certain types of algorithms, it may be helpful to be able to take a snapshot of an enumerator's state and rewind enumeration to that point.  Cloning the boxed value type would be a way of doing that.

Comment: @supercat That’s an interesting point actually. As far as I see it, however, rewinding enumerators is simply not supported by the framework. It would theoretically work in the specific case of `List<T>.Enumerator` (although not in the case you described before) but not in general since nothing in the `IEnumerator<T>` interface mandates that it’s copyable. I understand your use-case but even if you found a solution to clone value types it wouldn’t be supported by .NET.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: My point was that boxing a value type does not make it immutable, and while mutating boxed types is rather dubious, there are places, even in commonly-used parts of the Framework, where it happens.  A static method `ValueType MemberwiseClone(this ValueType src)` would be semantically well-defined when given any boxed value type, and would in some cases be semantically useful (it would have the same semantics as assigning one variable of the unboxed type to another). In cases where such a function could be used, one would usually know the underlying type, but perhaps not always.

Comment: @supercat Yes, I agree with your point (in this very special case). It’s a good complement to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private static T CloneUnboxed<T>(object o) where T : struct
    {
        return (T)o;
    }

    private static object CloneBoxed<T>(object o) where T : struct
    {
        return (object)(T)o;
    }
```

Although I do question the need for either, given that a value type ought to be immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the title and not the intent (in case someone finds this question), yes, cloning a boxed value type by value is supported via *[RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.getobjectvalue)*. For reference types, this method just returns the original reference, but for value types, it creates a new boxed object with the same value. For immutable value types, this is not necessary, as the instance should never be modified, but for mutable types, it is safe to use if you are passing the instance to code that could modify it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to cast the object to ValueType, would that not cause a clone to be made?  This could then be reboxed:

```
int i = 3;
object b = i; // box it
ValueType c = (ValueType) b; // unbox it
object d = c; // box it, effectively creating a clone
```

So, I think I would say an effective clone methodology would be:

```
object clone = (ValueType) boxed;
```

Comment: No, it won't. I've tested that, the ReferenceEquals method returns true when comparing b and c.

Comment: Have you tried comparing b and d, as these are the two boxed values?

Comment: OK, I have tried this myself and it seems that two boxing operations on the same value type result in the same box being used.  Thinking about it, this is sensible behaviour by the the CLR.

Comment: +1 I've tried this and it certainly looks like it works. Thx.

Comment: I tried it but it fails:
[TestMethod]
public void TestBoxAndUnbox()
{
    int i = 3;
    object b = i;
    ValueType c = (ValueType) b;
    object d = c;

    Assert.AreNotSame(b, d);
}

Comment: Yes, this is consistent with my findings (see my comment, above).  I think the CLR/compiler is realising that the same box can be reused although, for it to do this, it must realise that the value type is immutable.  I will have to investigate further.  I tried making the orginal int a volatile field but this did not help.

Comment: The rather-ironically-named "ValueType" is a class type, not a value type, so assigning it to Object will simply copy the reference.  Think of it as "ValueWrapper".